# How to download the worst audio quality with youtube-dl?

Tags: command-line, youtube, youtube-dl

I can't find a way to download the worst audio file quality of a video using `youtube-dl`, people ask how to download the best quality (and short answer is it automatically downloads the best) but what if I want the worst?

using the `-F` option I get this output :

[image]

Of course I could just type `-f 249` to manually choose the tiniest audio only file to download. But I am trying to make an automated system, to download the worst quality of any video, therefore I can't use this format (it may change).

I could use `--audio-format webm` but as you can see in the screenshot there are 3 candidates and again `youtube-dl` downloads the best of the three (the worst quality being the lowest in this webm format).

I could use `--audio-quality 9` but this is a post-processing option which means it will first download the best quality and then converts it afterwards (not bandwidth-friendly, my last option....).

What is a proper way to download the worst quality? (lastly I tried `-f worst -x` but it doesn't work)

**Edit** : Also, I know that I can use the output of `-F` and slice the lines to determine the worst audio available. But I am probing if there is any way to directly do that using `youtube-dl`

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried yet, but, according to the [docs](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#format-selection), you can use:

> **`wa, worstaudio`**: Select the worst quality audio-only format. Equivalent to **`worst*[vcodec=none]`**

Check the latest paragraphs on the ["Sorting Formats"](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#sorting-formats) section of the docs for more info.